# Perl Win32::API() return type

Tags: perl

Can anyone give an example of how a string can be returned from a call using `Win32::API()` function?  I need to return a string and print using `$val`. Please give an example if the same can be handled using  pointer as return type.

```
use Win32::API;  
my $res = new Win32::API('abc.dll','MyFun','_argument type list_','_Return type list_')or die $^E;  
my $val= $res->Call();   
print ($val);
```

Comment: actually in call() I have to pass a long and int pointer as the dll has the function like 'string MyFun(long a, int *b); So how will i put my return type buffer to pass using the same call() function that you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `Win32::API`'s `Call()` method](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-API/API.pm#CALLING_AN_IMPORTED_FUNCTION) suggests that you must pass `Call()` a scalar which will be used as a buffer to store the returned value; Call() itself will return whether the call succeeded or not.

Example:

```
my $return_buffer = " " x 80;
if ($res->Call(80, $return_buffer)) {
    print "OK, the API call returned '$return_buffer'\n";
} else {
    print "The API call failed for some reason.\n";
}
```

EDIT: quoting from [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-API/API.pm#CALLING_AN_IMPORTED_FUNCTION) for completeness:

The two parameters needed here are the length of the buffer that will hold the returned temporary path, and a pointer to the buffer itself. For numerical parameters, you can use either a constant expression or a variable, while for pointers you must use a variable name (no Perl references, just a plain variable name). Also note that memory must be allocated before calling the function, just like in C. For example, to pass a buffer of 80 characters to GetTempPath(), it must be initialized before with:

```
$lpBuffer = " " x 80;
```

This allocates a string of 80 characters. If you don't do so, you'll probably get Runtime exception errors, and generally nothing will work. The call should therefore include:

```
$lpBuffer = " " x 80;
$GetTempPath->Call(80, $lpBuffer);
```

And the result will be stored in the $lpBuffer variable. Note that you don't need to pass a reference to the variable (eg. you don't need \$lpBuffer), even if its value will be set by the function.

Comment: actually in call() I have to pass a long and int pointer as the dll has the function like 'string MyFun(long a, int *b); So how will i put my return type buffer to pass using the same call() function that you have mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious problem with the way you are doing this. The `Win32::API` module is capable of receiving a `char *` from a DLL function and transforming it into a Perl scalar. This code, for example, does what I expect:

```
use Win32::API;
$GetCommandLine = Win32::API->new('kernel32',
                                  'LPTSTR GetCommandLine()');
$val = $GetCommandLine->Call();
print "The command line of this program is: $val\n";
```

which is to print

```
The command line of this program is: C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe win32-api-string.pl
```

The obvious things are to check the return values as well as `$!` and `$^E` from every step of your code and that `abc.dll` is in your program's `$PATH`. You might want to drop the `.dll` from the function call (just say `Win32::API->new('abc', ...)` ) -- none of the examples ever explicitly include the `.dll` extension, and perhaps the module assumes that you *won't* use it (and will try to load a library from `abc.dll.dll` instead).

You also might want to try using [the Win32::API constructor from a prototype](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-API/API.pm#IMPORTING_A_FUNCTION_BY_PROTOTYPE), as I have done in my example. I find that this gives me fewer headaches setting the right argument and return types properly (but occasionally more headaches trying to shoe horn some object type into the [list of types that `Win32::API` supports out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102987/perl-win32api-return-type)). (The parameter list style constructor is now deprecated anyway, according to the v0.59 docs).